# How can I separate keywords from a file line by line in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, redhat

This is the sample text file:

```
134781.ux002jupiter!Cat_server8.99123.9.0: Login ****** Vegas     - csv111 - Versio 9.7 13.10.2016
141231.ux002jupiter!Cat_server8.99123.9.0: Logout ****** Madrid     - asd124 - Versio 9.7 13.10.1992
123456.ux002jupiter!Cat_server8.99123.9.0: Login ****** Oslo   - lks485 - Versio 9.7 13.10.1992
132541.ux002jupiter!Cat_server8.99123.9.0: Logout ****** Riyadh   - xcd785 - Versio 9.7 13.10.1992
```

I want to read this sample file line by line and want to separate keywords from this and maybe store in an array.

The output should be equivalent to (exact formatting doesn't matter):

```
["134781", "csv111", "Vegas", "Login"]
["141231", "asd124 ", "Vegas", "Logout "]
["121456", "lks485 ", "Vegas", "Login"]
["132541", "xcd785 ", "Vegas", "Logout "]
```

Please help out.

Comment: Bash is *really* not a good choice of languages for this job. The output array is in what format, JSONL? Bash doesn't have a compliant JSON generator, so if you had surprising usernames or locations the output could be malformed.

Comment: Also, don't flag questions as "urgent". *Everyone's* question is urgent to them, and saying that your own question is more urgent than anyone else's is rude.

Comment: No, the output is not JSON,  just array of strings. And I HAVE to use shell for this.

Comment: ...anyhow, the right place to start is to build a regex that matches the fields you want to extract. See in particular the `capture()` example in the [`jq` documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE).

Comment: But what you're showing us *isn't* an array of strings, at least, not in bash's meaning of the word "array". `["134781", "csv111", "Vegas", "Login"]` is not a bash array at all.

Comment: Array is not compulsory, extracting is more important. I can store in variables also.

Comment: Also, what possible contents can the `*****` sections contain? We can't write a regex for them unless we know what they look like when not anonymized.

Comment: Nothing ! It is the format. The file is like this.

Comment: These are just login information, that I need to send to Splunk after extracting those 4 parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203043/discussion-between-kush-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score -1):

The `=~` operator in `[[` can be used to store regular expression matches in an array.

```
re='^([[:digit:]]+)[.][^:]+:[[:space:]]([^[:space:]]+)*[[:space:]*]+([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+-[[:space:]]([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]'
while IFS= read -r line; do
   [[ $line =~ $re ]] || { echo "WARNING: Could not parse line: $line" >&2; continue; }
   declare -p BASH_REMATCH  # print the array's current content, or put your own code here
done <<'EOF'
134781.ux002jupiter!Cat_server8.99123.9.0: Login ****** Vegas     - csv111 - Versio 9.7 13.10.2016
141231.ux002jupiter!Cat_server8.99123.9.0: Logout ****** Madrid     - asd124 - Versio 9.7 13.10.1992
123456.ux002jupiter!Cat_server8.99123.9.0: Login ****** Oslo   - lks485 - Versio 9.7 13.10.1992
132541.ux002jupiter!Cat_server8.99123.9.0: Logout ****** Riyadh   - xcd785 - Versio 9.7 13.10.1992
EOF
```

...emits as output:

```
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="134781.ux002jupiter!Cat_server8.99123.9.0: Login ****** Vegas     - csv111 - " [1]="134781" [2]="Login" [3]="Vegas" [4]="csv111")
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="141231.ux002jupiter!Cat_server8.99123.9.0: Logout ****** Madrid     - asd124 - " [1]="141231" [2]="Logout" [3]="Madrid" [4]="asd124")
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="123456.ux002jupiter!Cat_server8.99123.9.0: Login ****** Oslo   - lks485 - " [1]="123456" [2]="Login" [3]="Oslo" [4]="lks485")
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="132541.ux002jupiter!Cat_server8.99123.9.0: Logout ****** Riyadh   - xcd785 - " [1]="132541" [2]="Logout" [3]="Riyadh" [4]="xcd785")
```

This output is a list of bash array definitions; `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` can thus be used to refer to the numbers at the beginning, `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` to refer to `Login` vs `Logout`, etc.